# make folder and named with datetime in php

Tags: php, csv, directory

is there any way to create directory and give name as a date today

i have php script that store csv to folder and i run everyday
i was thinking to group that csv file into each folder

for example
 perform getdate(); and create folder and named as indicate with date today, if i run again the script today, check first is any folder exist if not create, so php script will create folder and named as the date we run

i'm looking forward somebody guide me to do so
thanks

Comment: `mkdir('base/' . date('Y-m-d'));`

Answer (score 0):

out of the box

```
<?php
    $store_path = '/var/www/example/';
    $name = date('Y-m-d');
    if(!is_dir($store_path.$name)) mkdir($store_path.$name);
    $file_name = date('Y-m-d H-i-s').'.csv';
    #... your code
    #build your content and store it e.g. by
    file_put_contents($store_path.$name.'/'.$file_name, $yourcontent);
```